# Enthought Canopy Tcl/Tkinter error

Tags: enthought

I am working with a group of teachers using Canopy and we are trying to use Tkinter. About half the class is getting an error message when we run code that imports Tkinter. The error message we get is:

```
TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
 C:/Users/tg9154/AppData/Local/Enthought/Canopy/App/appdata/canopy-1.5.4.3105.win-x86_64/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/tg9154/AppData/Local/Enthought/Canopy/User/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/tg9154/AppData/Local/Enthought/Canopy/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/tg9154/AppData/Local/Enthought/Canopy/User/library C:/Users/tg9154/AppData/Local/Enthought/Canopy/library C:/Users/tg9154/AppData/Local/Enthought/Canopy/tcl8.5.2/library C:/Users/tg9154/AppData/Local/Enthought/tcl8.5.2/library 
This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I have tried all of the fixes I have found online and none of them are working.  I am wondering if a complete uninstall/install would work but I am hoping that there is a easier fix since I have so many teachers who would have to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

This bug on Windows in Canopy 1.5.3/1.5.4) was fixed in Canopy 1.5.5, released July 3.
To update to the current version of Canopy, see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website).